# Are Japanese Yen accepted in money exchange in Iran?

Tags: money, iran

I'm planning a trip to Iran, and most (if not all) the money I can bring would be in Japanese Yen.

Will it be easy to exchange ?

Every guide I read says that EUR GBP and USD are widely accepted but this not so helpful for me.

Comment: Can you not ask your bank at home to order Iranian currency for you and exchange there? Might be a tiny bit more expensive, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: "most (if not all) the money I can bring would be in Japanese Yen." - but... why? Can't you get USD/EUR wherever you are currently staying?

Comment: Exchanging the money twice is usually not the best move... unless there is no other option.

Comment: You would certainly be hit by a larger exchange margin when going directly from a second-tier currency (JPY) to a third-tier currency (IRR). On the other hand USD exchanges should be possible with a 1-2% loss.

Comment: JPY is accepted too and I don't think you will have any problem exchanging it.

Comment: @Meysam care to add your answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can exchange Japanese Yen in Iran, but it may be at less favorable rates and fewer locations.

[Farsinet](http://www.farsinet.com/toman/exchange.html)  explains:

> Iran has two exchange rates, one formally fixed by the Central Bank of Iran and another informal, open market rate that's sold to the public via currency exchange shops and traders on street corners (Street Rate).

Iranian Rial rate changes frequently but, on January 26, 2017, here's where it stood, per Farsinet's data:

**Official** => USD 32,360 =>**Street** => 38,490 
**Official** => Euro 34,806 =>**Street** => 42,100
**Official** => British Pound 40,965 =>**Street** => 48,900
**Official** => Japanese Yen 285 =>**Street** => 345
**Official** => Swiss Franc 32,406=> **Street** => 39,000
**Official** => China Yuan 4,704 =>**Street** => 5,600

What this means is that it may be more difficult to find an exchange shop or trader that will accept yen and, when it does, give you the best rate, as they give preference to other currency.

Again, Farisnet explains:

> The Unofficial-Street Exchange Rate used among small businesses and private transactions was much higher than official multi-exchange-rate prior to 2002. Since going to a single exchange rate the official and "Street-rate" have come much closer. The rates listed are based on the official exchange rate posted by the Iran Central Bank. We compare the official and "Street-rates" to ensure rates listed are the most accurate indicative of the true IRR-USD exchange rate. US Dollar (USD) is the most widely used foreign currency and the new $100 bills are preferred for street transactions and get the best rate.